# angular 9 : Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at MatSelect.ngAfterContentInit

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 9 and added angular material but when I want to use mat-select, I can not select the option and get the following error.

```
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at MatSelect.ngAfterContentInit (select.js:609)
    at callHook (core.js:4726)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at refreshView (core.js:12054)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13458)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11729)
    at refreshView (core.js:12064)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13404)
    at refreshView (core.js:12035)
```

Comment: Please share your code, preferably both TS and HTML files

Comment: since you want to use some of material's modules, you need to import them first to your `app.module.ts`. in your case this would probably be `MatSelectModule`. Let me know if that's what you're looking for

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. I copied same code(provided in their official doc page) and it is throwing this exact error. I have imported `MatSelectModule` in `app.module.ts` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `package.json` file and make sure your version is defined explicitly as defined on their site, and perhaps not too far behind your angular version. I'm using angular version 10.2.7 and my material version was 8.0.0. I've upgraded to 9.2.4 as on their site and its working now.